# How to restore public schema into different schema

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a dump, where the data and the structure is in the public schema. I want to restore it into a schema with a custom name - how can I do that?

EDIT V 2:

My dump file is from heroku, and looks like this at the beginning:

```
PGDMP
    !
pd6rq1i7f3kcath9.1.59.1.6<Y
0ENCODINENCODINGSET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
falseZ
00
STDSTRINGS
STDSTRINGS)SET standard_conforming_strings = 'off';
false[
126216385d6rq1i7f3kcatDATABASE?CREATE DATABASE d6rq1i7f3kcath WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';
DROP DATABASE d6rq1i7f3kcath;
uc0lt9t3fj0da4false26152200publicSCHEMACREATE SCHEMA public;
DROP SCHEMA public;
postgresfalse\
SCHEMA publicCOMMENT6COMMENT ON SCHEMA public IS 'standard public schema';
postgresfalse5?307916392plpgsql EXTENSION?CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
DROP EXTENSION plpgsql;
false]
00EXTENSION plpgsqlCOMMENT@COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';
false212?125516397_final_mode(anyarrayFUNCTION?CREATE FUNCTION _final_mode(anyarray) RETURNS anyelement
    LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
    AS $_$
      SELECT a
      FROM unnest($1) a
      GROUP BY 1
      ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, 1
      LIMIT 1;
    $_$;
,DROP FUNCTION public._final_mode(anyarray);
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false5?125516398mode(anyelement)    AGGREGATE?CREATE AGGREGATE mode(anyelement) (
    SFUNC = array_append,
    STYPE = anyarray,
    INITCOND = '{}',
    FINALFUNC = _final_mode
);
(DROP AGGREGATE public.mode(anyelement);
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false5224?125916399 advert_candidate_collector_failsTABLECREATE TABLE advert_candidate_collector_fails (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    advert_candidate_collector_status_id integer,
    exception_message text,
    stack_trace text,
    url text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);
4DROP TABLE public.advert_candidate_collector_fails;
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false5?125916405'advert_candidate_collector_fails_id_seSEQUENCE?CREATE SEQUENCE advert_candidate_collector_fails_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
>DROP SEQUENCE public.advert_candidate_collector_fails_id_seq;
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false1615^
00'advert_candidate_collector_fails_id_seqSEQUENCE OWNED BYeALTER SEQUENCE advert_candidate_collector_fails_id_seq OWNED BY advert_candidate_collector_fails.id;
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false162_
00'advert_candidate_collector_fails_id_seq
                                          SEQUENCE SETRSELECT pg_catalog.setval('advert_candidate_collector_fails_id_seq', 13641, true);
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false162?125916407#advert_candidate_collector_statusesTABLE?CREATE TABLE advert_candidate_collector_statuses (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    data_source_id character varying(120),
    state character varying(15) DEFAULT 'Queued'::character varying,
    source_name character varying(30),
    collector_type character varying(30),
    started_at timestamp without time zone,
    ended_at timestamp without time zone,
    times_failed integer DEFAULT 0,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone
);
7DROP TABLE public.advert_candidate_collector_statuses;
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false240424055?125916412*advert_candidate_collector_statuses_id_seSEQUENCE?CREATE SEQUENCE advert_candidate_collector_statuses_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
ADROP SEQUENCE public.advert_candidate_collector_statuses_id_seq;
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false1635`
00*advert_candidate_collector_statuses_id_seqSEQUENCE OWNED BYkALTER SEQUENCE advert_candidate_collector_statuses_id_seq OWNED BY advert_candidate_collector_statuses.id;
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false164a
00*advert_candidate_collector_statuses_id_seq
                                             SEQUENCE SETVSELECT pg_catalog.setval('advert_candidate_collector_statuses_id_seq', 133212, true);
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false164?125916414advertsTABLE"CREATE TABLE adverts (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    car_id integer NOT NULL,
    source_name character varying(20),
    url text,
    first_extraction timestamp without time zone,
    last_observed_at timestamp without time zone,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    source_id character varying(255),
    deactivated_at timestamp without time zone,
    seller_id integer NOT NULL,
    data_source_id character varying(100),
    price integer,
    availability_state character varying(15)
);

ROP TABLE public.adverts;
publicuc0lt9t3fj0da4false5?125916420adverts_id_seSEQUENCEpCREATE SEQUENCE adverts_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to restore the database with a different schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191653/i-want-to-restore-the-database-with-a-different-schema)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tometzky's solution isn't quite right, at least with 9.2's `pg_dump`. It'll create the table in the new schema, but `pg_dump` schema-qualifies the `ALTER TABLE ... OWNER TO` statements, so those will fail:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE demo;
\cCREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \c demo
You are now connected to database "demo" as user "postgres".
demo=# CREATE TABLE public.test ( dummy text );
CREATE TABLE
demo=# \d
        List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  |  Owner   
--------+------+-------+----------
 public | test | table | postgres
(1 row)
demo=# \q
$
$ pg_dump -U postgres -f demo.sql demo
$ sed -i 's/^SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;$/SET search_path = testschema, pg_catalog;/' demo.sql
$ grep testschema demo.sql 
SET search_path = testschema, pg_catalog;
$ dropdb -U postgres demo
$ createdb -U postgres demo
$ psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE SCHEMA testschema;' demo
CREATE SCHEMA
$ psql -U postgres -f demo.sql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -v QUIET=1 demo
psql:demo.sql:40: ERROR:  relation "public.test" does not exist
$ psql demo
demo=> \d testschema.test 
  Table "testschema.test"
 Column | Type | Modifiers 
--------+------+-----------
 dummy  | text |
```

You will also need to edit the dump to remove the schema-qualification on `public.test` or change it to the new schema name. `sed` is a useful tool for this.

I could've sworn the correct way to do this was with `pg_dump -Fc -n public -f dump.dbbackup` then `pg_restore` into a new schema, but I can't seem to find out exactly how right now.

Update: Nope, it looks like `sed` is your best bet. See [I want to restore the database with a different schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4191653/398670)

Answer (score 2):

Near the beginning of a dump file (created with `pg_dump databasename`) is a line:

```
SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;
```

Just change it to:

```
SET search_path = your_schema_name, pg_catalog;
```

Also you'll need to search for

```
ALTER TABLE public.
```

and replace with:

```
ALTER TABLE your_schema_name.
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? I think this is just setting the search_path in de restored database - not really restoring every thing from the dump INTO a specific schema - which was what I am looking for...

Comment: @NielsKristian Did you try it?

Comment: Well yes, and since my dump from heroku doesn't contain any SET search_path at all, then hmmm - what to do... (id didn't help to just add it :-)

Comment: @NielsKristian Ah, that fun with Heroku-is-mostly-but-not-quite-like-normal-PostgresQL stuff again. OK. What does the dump contain? Explicitly schema-qualified table names like `"public.t1"`?

Comment: @CraigRinger I added the 'head -n 100' lines of the dump, so you can have a better look :-)

Comment: @NielsKristian Aah, that's a custom-format dump, like `pg_dump -Fc` produces. As a last resort you can restore it to a temporary scratch DB, then dump the db in SQL format (`pg_dump` without `-Fc`) and use the hack described in my answer. I'm sure there's a better way, I just can't find it right now.