# How to duplicate schemas in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, foreign-key-relationship, postgresql-9.1

I have a database with schema `public` and `schema_A`. I need to create a new schema `schema_b` with the same structure than `schema_a`. 
I found the function below, the problem is that it does not copy the foreign key constraints.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clone_schema(source_schema text, dest_schema text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  object text;
  buffer text;
  default_ text;
  column_ text;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA ' || dest_schema ;

  -- TODO: Find a way to make this sequence's owner is the correct table.
  FOR object IN
    SELECT sequence_name::text FROM information_schema.SEQUENCES WHERE sequence_schema = source_schema
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || dest_schema || '.' || object;
  END LOOP;

  FOR object IN
    SELECT table_name::text FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = source_schema
  LOOP
    buffer := dest_schema || '.' || object;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || buffer || ' (LIKE ' || source_schema || '.' || object || ' INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING DEFAULTS)';

    FOR column_, default_ IN
      SELECT column_name::text, REPLACE(column_default::text, source_schema, dest_schema) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = dest_schema AND table_name = object AND column_default LIKE 'nextval(%' || source_schema || '%::regclass)'
    LOOP
      EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || buffer || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || column_ || ' SET DEFAULT ' || default_;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

How can I clone/copy `schema_A` with the foreign key constraints?

Comment: If you want to clone the schema with SQL query, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370614/copy-schema-and-create-new-schema-with-different-name-in-the-same-data-base/48732283#48732283) answer.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can probably do it from the command line without using files:

`pg_dump -U user --schema='fromschema' database | sed 's/fromschmea/toschema/g' | psql -U user -d database`

**Note** that this searches and replaces all occurrences of the string that is your schema name, so **it may affect your data**.

Comment: How can I avoid to affect the data?

Comment: @dani24 You can dump to a file and then use `grep -E "^[[:digit:]]+.*fromschema.*" dumpfile | wc -l` to count the occurrences of the schema name in the data rows.  If the result is greater than 0, you have data that contains the 'fromschema' string.

Answer (score 21):

I would use [**`pg_dump`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html) to dump the schema without data:

> ```
> -s
> --schema-only
> ```
>
> Dump only the object definitions (schema), not data.
>
> This option is the inverse of `--data-only`. It is similar to, but for historical reasons not identical to, specifying `--section=pre-data --section=post-data`.
>
> (Do not confuse this with the `--schema` option, which uses the word "schema" in a different meaning.)
>
> To exclude table data for only a subset of tables in the database, see `--exclude-table-data`.

```sh
pg_dump $DB -p $PORT -n $SCHEMA -s -f filename.pgsql
```

Then rename the schema in the dump (search & replace) and restore it with `psql`.

```
psql $DB -f filename.pgsql
```

**Foreign key constraints** referencing tables in *other* schemas are copied to point to the same schema.
References to tables within the *same* schema point to the respective tables within the copied schema.

Comment: Yes, thank you! but I wanted to avoid working with files. I'm looking for a quick way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

I will share a solution for my problem which was the same with a small addition. I needed to clone a schema, create a new database user and assign ownership of all objects in the new schema to that user.

For the following example let's assume that the reference schema is called **ref_schema** and the target schema **new_schema**. The reference schema and all the objects within are owned by a user called **ref_user**.

**1. dump the reference schema with pg_dump:**

```
pg_dump -n ref_schema -f dump.sql database_name
```

**2. create a new database user with the name *new_user*:**

```
CREATE USER new_user
```

**3. rename the schema *ref_schema* to *new_schema*:**

```
ALTER SCHEMA ref_schema RENAME TO new_schema
```

**4. change ownership of all objects in the renamed schema to the new user**

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY ref_user TO new_user
```

**5. restore the original reference schema from the dump**

```
psql -f dump.sql database_name
```

I hope someone finds this helpful.

Comment: i need to copy without data. What is the solution. Need only structures

Answer (score 6):

A bit late to the party but, some sql here could help you along your way:

**get schema oid:**

```
namespace_id = SELECT oid 
                  FROM pg_namespace 
                 WHERE nspname = '<schema name>';
```

**get table's oid:**

```
table_id = SELECT relfilenode 
                FROM pg_class 
               WHERE relnamespace = '<namespace_id>' AND relname = '<table_name>'
```

**get foreign key constraints:**

```
SELECT con.conname, pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid) AS condef 
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint AS con 
  JOIN pg_class AS cl ON cl.relnamespace = con.connamespace AND cl.relfilenode = con.conrelid 
 WHERE con.conrelid = '<table_relid>'::pg_catalog.oid AND con.contype = 'f';
```

A good resource for PostgreSQL system tables can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/catalogs.html). Additionally, you can learn more about the internal queries [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) makes to gather dump information by viewing it's [source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c).

Probably the easiest way to see how `pg_dump` gathers all your data would be to use [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) on it, like so:

```
$ strace -f -e sendto -s8192 -o pg_dump.trace pg_dump -s -n <schema>
$ grep -oP '(SET|SELECT)\s.+(?=\\0)' pg_dump.trace
```

You'll still have to sort through the morass of statements but, it should help you piece together a cloning tool programmatically and avoid having to drop to a shell to invoke `pg_dump`.

Comment: Here's a python class I just wrote up to perform a schema clone (including data copy) using all SQL and no shelling out to pg_dump: [https://gist.github.com/rabbitt/97f2c048d9e38c16ce62](https://gist.github.com/rabbitt/97f2c048d9e38c16ce62)

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into same. Sometimes I am missing remap_schema :)
The problem - neither from above addresses the Fc - standard format which is crucial for large schemas.
So I came up with something which uses it :
Pseudo code below - should work.
Requires rename of source for duration of pg_dump which, of course, might not be an option :(
**Source :**

```
pg_dump --pre-data in sql format
psql rename sosurce to target
pg_dump -Fc --data-only
psql rename back
pg_dump --post-data in sql format
```

**Target** :

```
sed source_schema->target_schema pre-data sql |psql
pg_restore Fc dump
sed source_schema->target_schema post-data sql |psql
```

sed above usually will include any other manipulations ( say different user names between source and target  ) But it will be way much faster as data will not be part of the file

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE DATABASE [Database to create]
WITH TEMPLATE [Database to copy]
OWNER [Your username];
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You could [modify](https://github.com/tindzk/postgres/commit/be7b60cb7dfd3806319fab0c4ec3345403541b5c) `pg_dump` not to emit schema names. To build a Docker image with these changes, create a `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/postgresql

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    alpine-sdk \
    perl \
    readline-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    bison \
    flex \
    git \
    coreutils \
    linux-headers \
    util-linux-dev

RUN git clone \
    --depth 1 \
    --branch feat/schema-less-pg-dump-11 \
    https://github.com/tindzk/postgres.git .

RUN ./configure && make

RUN cp src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump /usr/bin/ && \
    cp ./src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.so* /usr/lib/

RUN apk del alpine-sdk \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /usr/src/postgresql

CMD ["pg_dump"]
```

Then, run:

```bash
docker build -t pgdump-11 .
```

Now you can copy a database from the `public` schema into another schema in two steps:

```bash
docker run \
  -e PGPASSWORD=$db_password \
  -v "$(pwd)":/data/ \
  pgdump-11 \
  pg_dump \
  --verbose \
  --schema default \
  "postgres://$db_user@$db_host:$db_port/$db_name" \
  --file /data/dump.sql

(echo "drop schema $db_target_schema cascade; create schema $db_target_schema; set search_path = '$db_target_schema';"; cat dump.sql) | \
  psql "postgres://$db_user@$db_host:$b_port/$db_name"
```

The benefit of this approach is that the source schema does not need to be renamed which would otherwise require downtime.