# How force pg_dump to (not) include scheme name for each objects in DDL

Tags: postgresql, ddl, pg-dump, db-schema

I need compare 2 DBs schemes (DDLs) - **Postgress 9.5**

Im executing below command on both servers:

```
pg_dump -U postgres --dbname=db--schema-only -f schema.sql
```

But I noticed one of output prefixes each objects by scheme name, eg

> CREATE FUNCTION schemeName.function_name

while the other doesntm eg:

> CREATE FUNCTION function_name

Is there any option in pg_dump where I can decide to inculde or not scheme names in output DDL?
(Preference is at least remove those schema prefixes...)

Answer (score 1):

In short:you can't. But, you can use `sed` to automate *most* of your editing.

---

```
#!/bin/sh

# dump only schema "tmp"
# force quoted identifiers
# use sed to strip them
# [youstillneedtoremove the "CReate SCHEMA $SCH_NAME-stuff

DB_NAME="postgres"

pg_dump -Upostgres -n tmp --schema-only --quote-all-identifiers $DB_NAME \
   | sed 's/"tmp"\.//g' > tmp_schema_stripped.sql

#EOF
```

Comment: So why one engine adds that buy other not? I have dozen of schemas per database not easy to filter out all of those

Comment: **You** created the schemas (for a reason) Just deal with it. [and;sed is your friend]

Comment: Wasn't me actually but app vendor... Still do not understand why one db instance add schemas ahead but other not? I'm okay to have those or not - as long as same methodology is used on both engines BTW one instance is installed on windows another on Linux box (if this make any difference...)

Comment: If no option to force dump to do / not include schema names in output script - can you please advise query which allows extract all schemes in selected database? Then I could call several times dump, sed and merge all together

Comment: I just noticed I have similar behavior on other Linux box (adding scheme names) - might it be because of different version of pg_dump tools ?

Comment: Sadly, `pg_dump` does not support this behaviour out-of-the-box. Using `sed` is not ideal since the replacements would have to be context-aware to avoid false positives. As an alternative, you could make a few changes to the `pg_dump` source code to achieve the desired outcome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216462/how-to-duplicate-schemas-in-postgresql/77644723#77644723