# Why is my Rails `db/schema.rb` prefixing functions with `public`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Upon rebuilding my Postgresql database from a dump file using `pg_restore`, my schema file `db/schema.rb` is now prefixing the `gen_random_uuid()` function with `public`.

`create_table "cars", id: :uuid, default: -> { "public.gen_random_uuid()" }`

How can I prevent from the schema file from prefixing method calls with `public`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem isn't rails specific, more `pg_dump` specific. If you read the dump, it probably creates the functions with the `public.` prefix?

Here's a similar problem which might help you out: [How force pg_dump to (not) include scheme name for each objects in DDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146760/how-force-pg-dump-to-not-include-scheme-name-for-each-objects-in-ddl)

Answer (score -4):

Try adding `config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false` in your environment's config file, e.g. `#config/environments/production.rb` (in the project you are dumping from), then dump and restore the db again on your local env.

Comment: This will not work for me, as I am required to have `db/schema.rb` created/updated upon running `rails db:migrate`