# Too many server roundtrips w/ psycopg2

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2, executemany

I am making a script, that should create a schema for each customer. I’m fetching all metadata from a database that defines how each customer’s schema should look like, and then create it. Everything is well defined, the types, names of tables, etc. A customer has many tables (fx, address, customers, contact, item, etc), and each table has the same metadata.

My procedure now:

1. get everything I need from the metadataDatabase.
2. In a for loop, create a table, and then Alter Table and add each metadata (This is done for each table).

Right now my script runs in about a minute for each customer, which I think is too slow. It has something to do with me having a loop, and in that loop, I’m altering each table.
I think that instead of me altering (which might be not so clever approach), I should do something like the following:
Note that this is just a stupid but valid example:

```
for table in tables:
    con.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tester.%s (%s, %s);", (table, "last_seen   date", "valid_from    timestamp"))
```

But it gives me this error (it seems like it reads the table name as a string in a string..):

*psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'billing'"*

*LINE 1: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tester.'billing' ('last_seen   da...*

Comment: Please provide fuller background to your [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to call `ALTER TABLE`? Why can't you *only* use `CREATE TABLE`? Why do you need to automate DDL commands in application layer code? Databases should be manual, sit-down, planned and designed events, anticipating all needs and scopes, and should not be handled in code like Python with automation only its data content. You should know in advance all needed schemas, tables, fields, types, etc. Otherwise this is may not be an ideal database design.

Comment: You are right. My bad. I have edited the question. Maybe you will understand my problem better now.

Comment: What is your question though: performance per your title or posted, specific error? For latter, you cannot parameterize identifiers like table names but can use psycopg2's [`sql.Identifier`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating tables with a `serial` type (i.e., autonumber) ID field and then use alter table for all other fields by using a *combination* of `sql.Identifier` for identifiers (schema names, table names, column names, function names, etc.) and regular format for data types which are not literals in SQL statement.

```
from psycopg2 import sql

# CREATE TABLE
query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {shm}.{tbl} (ID serial)"""

cur.execute(sql.SQL(query).format(shm = sql.Identifier("tester"),
                                  tbl = sql.Identifier("table")))

# ALTER TABLE
items = [("last_seen", "date"), ("valid_from", "timestamp")]    
query = """ALTER TABLE {shm}.{tbl} ADD COLUMN {col} {typ}"""

for item in items:
    # KEEP IDENTIFIER PLACEHOLDERS
    final_query = query.format(shm="{shm}", tbl="{tbl}", col="{col}", typ=i[1])
    cur.execute(sql.SQL(final_query).format(shm = sql.Identifier("tester"), 
                                            tbl = sql.Identifier("table"),
                                            col = sql.Identifier(item[0]))
```

Alternatively, use `str.join` with list comprehension for one `CREATE TABLE`:

```
query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {shm}.{tbl} (
       "id" serial,
       {vals}
)"""

items = [("last_seen", "date"), ("valid_from", "timestamp")]  
val = ",\n       ".join(["{{}} {typ}".format(typ=i[1]) for i in items])

# KEEP IDENTIFIER PLACEHOLDERS
pre_query = query.format(shm="{shm}", tbl="{tbl}", vals=val)

final_query = sql.SQL(pre_query).format(*[sql.Identifier(i[0]) for i in items], 
                                        shm = sql.Identifier("tester"), 
                                        tbl = sql.Identifier("table"))    
cur.execute(final_query)
```

**SQL** *(sent to database)*

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "tester"."table" (
       "id" serial,
       "last_seen" date,
       "valid_from" timestamp
)
```

Comment: In the first example why don't you do everything the creating stage, instead of doing it partly in create and partly in alter ?

Comment: That's what I am showing in second example. First is much simpler and intended to adjust your original setup. However, second example involves dynamically concatenating with `join` and more extensive a solution. Please test on your end to see if it works.

Comment: Hi again. Sorry for the late reply. Christmas and stuff was calling.
I have now tried. It works but it's still a bit too slow. Is it possible to make the cur.execute(final_query) for multiple tables at once, instead of having to do it for each table?
Fx., as it is now: If I have 50 tables, I need to make the execution for every table. But is there a way where I can collect all the SQL queries and execute them all in one big batch?

Comment: Consider building a stored function, placing all DDL statements, then call it. Alternatively, [duplicate schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18216462/1422451) for each customer using `psql` which Python can call at command line. Google/Bing search on how to deploy multi-tenancy in Postgres.

Comment: You have been a great help. Thanks.
Can I use sql.Identifier to alter tables and add foreign key constraints? Because, when I try, it somehow doesn't recognise the table I am making the reference to.

Comment: You can use `sql.Identifier` for *any* identifier in *any* DDL or DML SQL statements. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

> However, this becomes heavy as there are too many server roundtrips.

How many tables with how many columns are you creating that this is slow?  Could you ssh to a machine closer to your server and run the python there?

I don't get that error.  Rather, I get an SQL syntax error.  A values list is for conveying data.  But ALTER TABLE is not about data, it is about metadata.  You can't use a values list there.  You need the names of the columns and types in double quotes (or no quotes) rather than single quotes.  And you can't have a comma between name and type.  And you can't have parentheses around each pair.  And each pair needs to be introduced with "ADD", you can't have it just once.  You are using the wrong tool for the job.  execute_batch is almost the right tool, except it will use single quotes rather than double quotes around the identifiers.  Perhaps you could add a flag to it tell it to use quote_ident.

Not only is execute_values the wrong tool for the job, but I think python in general might be as well.  Why not just load from a `.sql` file?

Comment: Hi.Thank you for your answer, it seems like I haven't been clear in my question. I have therefore made an edit of the question, that should hopefully make it easier for you to help.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever Your new question still has the problem of treating metadata as if it were data.  You would need to bypass the psycopg2 bind variables, which only work for data, and use quote_ident instead.