# Clone a Postgres schema programatically

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I need to clone a Postgres schema programatically in nodejs.

I have tried this approach

[How to duplicate schemas in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216462/how-to-duplicate-schemas-in-postgresql)

but it is quite old and could not make it work.

I have tried using pg_dump with -s flag to copy the schema structure then replacing in that file all the ocurrencies of the original schema for the new schema name.

Then i run psql instead of pg_restore because the file is not compatible with that command.

```
psql lims -U lims -h localhost -f new_schema.dump
```

psql:new_schema.dump:1127: ERROR:  no existe el esquema «cliente2»

How could i create the schema programatically?

Comment: I think you will need to do the heavy lifting here yourself.  Was "cliente2" the destination schema you were **trying** to use?  Was there not a CREATE SCHEMA command for it in the post-replacement file?  Was there not a CREATE SCHEMA in the original dump file?

Answer (score 3):

I think the most robust and sanity-preserving option is to use the database software itself to rename the schema.  So something like this:

```
pg_dump -s -n old_schema > dmp_old.sql
createdb scratch_db_465484
psql scratch_db_465484 -1 -f dmp_old.sql
psql scratch_db_465484 -c 'alter schema old_schema rename to new_schema'
pg_dump scratch_db_465484 -s -n new_schema > dmp_new.sql
psql -1 -f dmp_new.sql
dropdb scratch_db_465484
```

I think the main problem here would be any extensions which installed their objects into old_schema would not get dumped but might be depended upon.

Comment: Ahhh. You create a new database (temporal) to rename the schema and then insert it back to the original database. I will try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that:

- you created dump of schema
- than search-replace old schema name to new. I suppose it's `cliente2` in your case
- then you tried to run it on postgresql

#### Problem: "file is not compatible with that command"

I suppose you forgot to run

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA cliente2;
```

before running your script.

That's why you have an error message that schema cliente2 not exists.

#### Other (possible) problems

A. Most probably auto-generated script will need manual edit to be correct. Especially if you copied schema `public` into new schema.

B. Usually you need to add GRANTs for users to use schema and objects inside it.

Comment: I thought the `CREATE SCHEMA cliente2` was included in the generated script but it wasn´t. Running that command manually solved the problem.