# In postgresql , I am getting duplicates in a schema when I restore some tables in to a other schema in the same db .why?

Tags: postgresql, database-schema, postgresql-9.4, rails-postgresql

In postgres 9.5 , I have a db called test. where I have 2 schemas
1.public 
2. testcase
when i try to restore tables from public to testcase shema. I creates duplicates in public schema and I couldn't view even a single table in testcase schema aftre the restoration. But it doesn't shows any error

Comment: what you call duplicates?.. rows that "break" PK?..

Comment: My status is,I have taken backup (.backup) from pubic schema and restored that in to another schema (from the same db) .when i do this all the tables (without any constrains such as uniqueId / primarykey) insert one more row from the backup file in the public schema. also I couldn't see any tables in my new schema . But restoration done without any errors. Why this

Comment: please elaborate the post. add code, errors and precise actions list

Comment: *********DB***********

Comment: *******************db- test************shcemas-public,test2,tets3*******public-table1,table2,table3*************

Comment: I just backuped the public schema and backuped all the 3tables and restored it to an empty schema called"test2"

Comment: But unfortunately I had 1 table with no cosntraints like priary key or unique key. That is table1. so when I did this restoration to test2 , the data in  the table1 duplicated by simply restored the data from backup file.

Comment: this is meant behaviour. Postgres does not "analyze" backup file before restoring (because it can't guess, how exactly you want to restore the data). you could use -c `clean` if you used `pg_restore`, so it would `DROP` and recreate table before loading data. If you  wanted PITR recover - you should use different approach.

Comment: the behavious is if I restore a backup from public schema to any other schema , it is restored to public schema too. is that mean i am doing something wrong here. I am using Dbeaver GUI for this. Not commands

Comment: ah - I see. I have no idea how Dbeaver GUI does it. sorry. when you dont mention the backup command I assume you use pg_dump.

Comment: If you dont mind can you pls tell me the cokmands for both operations. taking public schema backup and restore to a particular schema.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191653/i-want-to-restore-the-database-with-a-different-schema

Comment: Thankzz a lot bro

Comment: I hav edone the restoration using commands. but it doesn't show m,y tables in the new schema.